# How to upload images to kentico app themes folder

Tags: image, kentico, app-themes

I have just started working for a new company and they have their website created using Kentico. There are images stored at the following location:

```
App_Themes/companyname/v3/content/call.gif" alt="call us">
```

How can I access the app themes folder from within Kentico CMS desk so that I can upload new images and replace them with a path similar to what is already there? I can not seem to locate the images already uploaded via the CMS desk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was locked down to FTP only as I was using version 5.5.

The ~/App_Themes/ is an application folder which is located on the file server.  In order to upload images to this folder you need to have access to the server where Kentico is running and manually put the files inside this folder. In Kentico 6 and higher you can manage the files in this folder in the UI in Site manager -> CSS stylesheets -> your stylesheet -> Theme, but this option is not available for version 5.5